# Postsharp OnMethodBoundryAspect on interface implementation

Tags: c#, interface, aop, postsharp

I have code that roughly looks like this

```
IInterface {

   public MyClass GetSomething();
}

public MyService : IInterface {

   [NeverNull]
   public GetSomething() {
       if (canAccess) {
          return new MyClass();
       }
       return null;
   }
}

[Serializable]
public NeverNullAttribute : OnMethodBoundryAspect {
     OnSuccess(MethodExecutionArgs args ) {
         if (args.ReturnValue == null){
             args.ReturnValue = new MyClass();
         }
     }
}
```

Now my attribute seems to be used if i call code like this

```
public void SomeMethod() {
     var myService = new MyService();
     Assert.IsNotNull(myService.GetSomething()); //this always works


     var interface = //use unity to get a instance instance of MyService
     Assert.IsNotNull(interface.GetSomething()); //this can fail since GetSomething is properly executed, but the NeverNull aspect doesn't seem to be executed.
}
```

My real code is a bit more involved but i hope this demonstrates the problem, namely that the OnSuccess doesn't get executed if i use the interface way of calling the method.

I use postsharp express. It would be an option to upgrade if i was certain it would solve this problem.

Update: I made the methods virtual as suggested, this seems to have no effect. ON other places where i directly create a instance of a class with attributes it does work so i know something of postsharp is working.

Update: Could it be that the aspects (which are defined in another project) are not weaved in my code properly?

Comment: Are you sure that both variables (myService and interface) hold a reference to an object of the same class? Maybe a proxy object is used in the second place.

Comment: I know for certain that the GetSomething method is actually executed. Would a proxy object prevent The OnMethodBoundryAspect to work? I thought the idea behind Postsharp/IL weaving was that it could ensure any call to my GetSomething could get intercepted regardless of proxies/inheritance/etc but this could be my limited experience with postsharp

Comment: You can check while debugging which instance you hold in the variable. Method aspects are only inherited, if the method is abstract or marked as virtual. You can read about the behavior in inheritance scenarios [on the PostSharp blog](http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/deeper-into-aspect-inheritance). Furthermore, if you need that all implementations of the IInterface have that behavior, you can add the aspect directly to the interface as well.

Comment: I DO ONLY want the aspect on this specific implementation. I'll try making my method virtual and see if that works. I didn't expect that to be an issue since i don't inherit an aspect from a parent method.

Comment: when debugging it doesn't seem to generate proxies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that PostSharp was included but for some reason it wasn't enabled on the project containing MyService.
for anyone else having issues, due to IL-Weaving (the awsomeness of postsharp) the aspect OnEntry/OnSuccess will be INSIDE the method if you look at your method using IL SPY. the method should for example look like this

```
public SomeObject GetSomething(){
    MethodExecutionArgs methodExecutionArgs = new MethodExecutionArgs(null, null);

    /* original method code here */ 

    methodExecutionArgs.ReturnValue = returnValue;
    <>z__a_1.a0.OnSuccess(methodExecutionArgs);
    return (SomeObject)methodExecutionArgs.ReturnValue;
}
```

However i noticed that the postsharp code wasn't there on this specific method (in this project) and it was on other places where i was using my postsharp aspect.

For some reason even the enable postsharp button on my project properties wasn't working either so i had to manual edit my csproj file.

It would be nice if there was some way to detect at compile time that postsharp wasn't loaded properly.

Comment: In the latest PostSharp version (3.1.x), the check whether the PostSharp has been correctly imported is performed in *.csproj file. If the problem was in *.csproj file, then even the actual check could not be performed. Including PostSharp targets also defines constant POSTSHARP, which you can test in your code with `#if !POSTSHARP` and `#error PostSharp is not imported`.